# How equal array with empty?

Tags: php, html

Sir i have some problem about array. this is my code

```
$isi = array('1','6','7','9','4');

    $cekarray = array('1','6','2');

    if(!empty($cekarray[$isi]))
    {
        echo "b = ".1."<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "b = ".0."<br>";
    }
```

i hope output it should be look like

```
b = 1
b = 1
b = 0
```

thanks before sir

Comment: You don;t understand array basics. Read manuals first.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do here.

Comment: Are you trying to do an array_intersect()?

Comment: maybe, just maybe, a wild guess, you are looking for `in_array()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to find out which items in the `$cekarray` exist in the `$isi` array.

Here is one simple method of doing that

```
<?php
$isi = array('1','6','7','9','4');

$cekarray = array('1','6','2');

foreach ( $cekarray as $val) {
    if ( in_array($val, $isi) ) {
        echo "b = 1<br>";
    } else {
        echo "b = 0<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot sir.. :)

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: excuse me sir, can i talk again?
how can i get some data from if ?
 if ( in_array($val, $isi) ) {
        echo "b = 1<br>";
        $r = 1;
    } else {
        echo "b = 0<br>";
        $r = 0
    }

how i can get data $r? 
$r = [1,1,0];
thanks before sir.

Comment: Yes go ahead I am listening

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the values from $cekarray are present in $isi, this should give the desired output:

```
$isi = array('1','6','7','9','4');
$cekarray = array('1','6','2');

foreach ($cekarray as &$cekarrayValue) {
    foreach ($isi as &$isiValue) {
        if($cekarrayValue==$isiValue)
            echo "b = 1<br />";
        else
            echo "b = 0<br />";
    }
}
```

Well, only in this case. Depending on what you want, functionality must be added but it's a start. You can also take a look at in_array() function.